# What does なんか文句あんのかな、何のお悩みか？ mean

Tags: meaning

This sentence is a little baffling to me.

The context is that someone is responding to a question with this sentence.

I have tried to translate, and so far I get this:

> I wonder if the idea of words like these, any trouble?

I'm pretty sure my translation is off. Like I said, this sentence is baffling to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> なんか文句あんのかな、何のお悩みか？ : (lit.) I wonder if you have a complain or something, what is your concern?

It could be separated in two sentences like this:

> なんか文句あんのかな。何のお悩みか？

Which would be better...

Also, あん is basically an oral contraction for ある.

Now if you want to translate it in a natural English, you could probably omit "I wonder", use contractions in English as well (what is -> what's) etc.

Comment: Agree with the answer. Just want to point out that あん is contracted ある**の**.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! This sentence has me stumped! I should have known there was a contraction in there!